# Defining a merged cell when reading an xlsx document (Apache POI) Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, apache-poi

There is a document in which some cells are combined with a group of others and if it is not the upper left cell (groups of combined cells) then when reading this cell, you can get a null value.
How to determine if this cell is just empty, or is it combined? In case it is combined (and not the top left) I need to get this value somehow.

in general, two main questions:

1. How to determine if a cell is merged?
2. If a cell is merged, how to get a value (instead of null)?

The screenshot shows which cell I need. But since my application selects a row and a column based on user data, it tries to get data from cell N11
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNYcE.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can get merged regions via `mergedRegions` method in sheet object

For example, how I check cell for merge and nullable:

```
fun getValue(sheet: Sheet, cell: Cell?): String {
    if (cell == null) return ""
    for(region in sheet.mergedRegions){
        if(region.isInRange(cell)) {
            return sheet.getRow(region.firstRow).getCell(region.firstColumn).stringCellValue
        }
    }
    return cell.stringCellValue ?: ""
}
```